# Find the fundamental group of the following spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology

2. Find the fundamental groups of the following spaces. In each case they
   can be built up from cyclic groups by free products and direct products.

(a) The space obtained from two copies of the torus $S^1\times S^1$ by identifying the simple closed curve $S^1\times\{1\}$ on the first copy of the torus with the simple closed curve $S^1 \times \{1\}$ on the second copy of the
torus.

(b) The space obtained from a torus $S^1 \times S^1$ by joining two distinct
points $a$ and $b$ on it by an arc which meets the torus only in its two endpoints $a$ and $b$

My trouble is with the second one, I don't know how to apply Van Kampen's theorem to this space.

Comment: Well you know the fundamental group for the torus if you did part (a), so find two open sets in the space described in part (b) and apply the theorem again.

Comment: Interesting. I know the fundamental group of the torus is $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ from outside the problem, but I don't even recognize how part (a) relates to part (b).

Comment: For (b) you can take a nbhd of the circle containing $a$  and $b$, and then a nbhd of the torus. You can also homotope the space to a wedge of the torus and circle.

Comment: I didn't know if I was allowed to consider the two points of intersection as the same point via a homotopy. In that case, the solution would be $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ free product with $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yes. Now try to work it out with the van Kampen theorem!